# gulp Ошибка Error: Cannot find module 'webp-converter/cwebp' Как исправить?

Tags: gulp, сборка, плагин, настройка

Собрал сбоку gulp
[по уроку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stFOy0Noahg&t=3929s&ab_channel=%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8-IT%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81)
После установки плагина `gulp-webpcss` командой: `npm i gulp-webpcss --save-dev`, настройки плагина и запуска `gulp`получаю ошибку

> Error: Cannot find module 'webp-converter/cwebp'

как ее исправить? Попробовал еще установить плагин `npm i gulp-webp-css --save-dev` (поменял в gulpfile.js). Тогда никах ошибок сборки не возникает, но вместо содержимого сайта открывается вкладка error с сообщением `Cannot GET /`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ:

Нужно установить webp-converter командой:

```
npm i webp-converter@2.2.3 --save-exact
```